# How to retrieve a parent style?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm getting an error in my styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Animation.TypingFilterRestore" >
</style>
```

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Answer (score 0):

thre is no default theme with given if you define the parent style please post the parent style code also.. or check may be it is `@android:style/Animation.Translucent`

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of aapt, you'll see this error.This happens now because aapt is stricter with regards to style parenting. Before, if there was no parent, it would just ignore this oversight; now it requires a parent.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Rename the style so that it doesn't use implicit parenting with dots.
2. Create the parent styles. They could either be empty, or you could actually use them for something.

Please see [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2011/08/new-to-android-more-style-restrictions.html)

Comment: can you please tell me how to do one of the solutions ?

Comment: yes i know, im asking for you to tell me how to do anyone of them.. im new to android development, when i change the style parent for example to parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity" or anything else, i get tons of error in my activity.xml.